# Java: Unable to locate the resource file with locales

Tags: java, locale

The following code

```
package com.my.exercise;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String language = "en";
        String country = "US";

        Locale l = new Locale(language, country);
        ResourceBundle r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", l);

        String str = r.getString("wish"); // Prints "Happy Birthday"
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

works for my sample application with the following folder structure when **Resource Bundle 'Bundle'** is located in **src** folder:

[image]

But the same code fails with error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Bundle, locale en_US" when **Resource Bundle 'Bundle'** is placed inside **src/main** folder:

[image]

Problem: What do I need to modify in my code in order to make **Resource Bundle 'Bundle'** inside **src/main** folder to be discoverable?

Comment: If your code is in src/main/java, it would appear your project structure is following Maven conventions, in which case your resources need to reside in src/main/resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your advise, VGR! Indeed, there was a Maven project in the back-end. I submitted the code despite it was unable to find the resource files in my local Idea project, but it did pass the compilation on the server. I just ensured that I used the Resource Bundle location within **src/main** folder.

[image]